# Laravel 5.1 and Cashier not interacting with $user as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-cashier

When I register a new user, Cashier's methods work fine to register that user.  For instance, I have this in my User model:

```
public static function registerUser()
{
$user = new User;
$stripeToken = Input::get('stripeToken');
$user->subscription('yearly')->create($stripeToken);
$user->save();
}
```

I also have a "resubscribe" method in my User model that uses similar Cashier methods:

```
public static function resubscribe(){
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $email)->first();
    if ($user->everSubscribed()) {
        $credentials = Input::only(['email', 'password']);
        $stripeToken = Input::get('stripeToken');
        $user->subscription('monthly')->resume($stripeToken);
        $user->save(); 
     }
}
```

and I get the following error:  "Call to undefined method stdClass::everSubscribed()".

If I remove that condition, I get the following error: "FatalErrorException in User.php line 124:  Call to undefined method stdClass::subscription()"

If I replace these lines of code:

```
$email = Input::get('email');
$user = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $email)->first();
```

with this:

```
$user = new User;
```

Then I get no errors, but of course, I don't want to create a new User, I want to resubscribe my old user.  I had this working fine in Laravel 4.2 with nearly identical code.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Eloquent instead of the Query Builder:

$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

The query builder `DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $email)->first()` returns a `stdClass` object rather than an instance of your User model.